# find nonbreaking period with condition

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.2

There are quotas for hotels per day in a table. How to get number of days when hotel is daily available?

```
q_id    q_hotel q_date  q_value
1   1   2013-02-01  1
2   1   2013-02-02  1
3   1   2013-02-03  1
4   1   2013-02-04  0
5   1   2013-02-05  2
6   1   2013-02-06  3
7   1   2013-02-07  3
8   1   2013-02-08  2
9   1   2013-02-09  0
10  1   2013-02-10  0
11  1   2013-02-11  1
12  1   2013-02-12  1
```

Wanted output:

```
q_hotel q_date  days_available
1   2013-02-01  3
1   2013-02-02  2
1   2013-02-03  1
1   2013-02-04  0
1   2013-02-05  4
1   2013-02-06  3
1   2013-02-07  2
1   2013-02-08  1
1   2013-02-09  0
1   2013-02-10  0
1   2013-02-11  2
1   2013-02-12  1
```

For now I can get number of days if there is zero quote after needed date exists - I find closest unavailable day and calculate dates difference.
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/1a64c/14

```
    select q_hotel
  ,q_date
  ,(select extract(day from (min(B.q_date)-A.q_date)) from Table1 B where B.q_date>A.q_date
   and B.q_value=0 and A.q_value<>0)
from Table1 A
```

But there is a problem when I don't have a zero closing date.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/1a64c/14

Comment: What's `q_value`? Not a super-informative column name.... Number of vacancies? As for the question, it sounds like you want to find "for each day within the covered range, the number of consecutive subsequent days in which at least one vacancy is available." CorrecT?

Comment: Also, is it guaranteed that the entries in the input table will be contiguous? i.e. Will there ever be "2013-02-01" followed by "2013-02-03", skipping an entry for "2013-02-02"? If so, should zero vacances be assumed for 02?

Comment: Contiguous - not guaranteed, missing dates means zero vacances. q_value - yes, number of vacancies.

Comment: OK. To handle missing dates you'll probably have to do a left outer join against a `generate_series( (select min(q_date) from table1), (select max(q_ate from table1), interval '1' day )`

Comment: I planned to avoid missing dates while counting difference between range borders plus one day and q_value::boolean. Means that range "2013-02-01" - "2013-02-03" should have sum(q_value::boolean)=3. If "2013-02-02" will be missed than sum() will not match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution:

```
select
    a.q_date
,   a.q_hotel
,   case
        when
            a.q_value = 0
        then
            0
        else
        (
            select
                extract
                ( day from
                    min ( b.q_date ) - a.q_date + interval '1 day'
                )
            from    table1 b
            where   b.q_date >= a.q_date
            and     b.q_hotel = a.q_hotel
            and not exists
            (
                select  1
                from    table1 c
                where   c.q_date = b.q_date + interval '1 day'
                and     b.q_hotel = a.q_hotel
                and     q_value <> 0
            )
        )
    end as days_available
from    table1 a
```